# Linear regression loop and coefficient extraction error

Tags: r, error-handling, linear-regression, coefficients

I basically want to run 1000 linear regressions (very simple, Y~X) and extract the coefficients from each one. Each regression is in "chunks" of 200 observations for Y, since the X remains the same for each regression. This is what I have:

```
X<-rgamma(200,23,2)

U_list <- replicate(1000,rnorm(200,0,1),simplify = FALSE)
U_list <- setNames(U_list,paste0("U",seq_along(U_list)))

U<-unlist(U_list)

Y_list<-0.6+0.4*X+U
Y_list<-setNames(Y_list,paste0("Y",seq_along(Y_list)))

Y<-unlist(Y_list)
```

In order to try this, I attempted a for loop

```
k<-seq(from=1, to=200000, by=200)
for(i in k){
  assign(paste0("reg", i), lm(Y[i:199+i]~X))
}
```

I had in mind that with this loop I would be doing something like this

```
reg1<-lm(Y[1:200]~X)
reg2<-lm(Y[201:400]~X) etc.
```

But the following error appears, and I don't quite understand it, because if I do the regressions one by one, I get a result

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y[i:199 + i] ~ X, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'X')
```

For the coefficient extraction, I thought of some rbind(), but I'm not quite sure if that could result. If it is not a lot to ask, I would appreciate the help, since I am still learning how to program and sometimes it is frustrating!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve your problem with another data structure, that makes it easier to apply a function to multiple elements - the `data.frame`:

```
X<-rgamma(200,23,2)

Y <- replicate(1000,rnorm(200,0,1),simplify = T)

Mat <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y))

names(Mat) <- c("X",paste("Y",1:1000,sep="_"))

Coeffs <- as.data.frame(t(apply(Mat[,2:ncol(Mat)],2,function(col){
  mod <- lm(col ~ Mat[,"X"])
  return(mod$coefficients)
})))

head(Coeffs,10)

     (Intercept)   Mat[, "X"]
Y_1    0.1616418 -0.007862732
Y_2    0.3841935 -0.030134746
Y_3   -0.4244851  0.044787500
Y_4    0.2059972 -0.017895949
Y_5    0.5207483 -0.048730507
Y_6    0.5163610 -0.036493825
Y_7    0.3589379 -0.038667216
Y_8   -0.2291387  0.025178289
Y_9   -0.1274423  0.010477415
Y_10  -0.6508141  0.047532979
```